# can't deploy mean stack on azure

Tags: angular, azure, stack, mean-stack, angular7

I'm trying to run my mean stack app on azure but it's running the default page instead of my app. How can I run my app on azure after pushing it into azure?

I tried to run my app on azure but it didn't work. I followed all the steps, one by one, but every time I try to run my app, it runs the default microsoft page instead of it.

I expect an output of my web application page instead of the microsoft default page.

Comment: Is this an Azure app service? Are you hitting the *.azurewebsites.net address or a custom address? Problems with Azure could be caused by a wide range of issues, so we'll need as many details as possible on this to help out.

Comment: Yes web application using mean stack

Comment: You might take a look at this link for more insights https://techbrij.com/azure-app-services-github-deploying-mean